# Railsチュートリアル 「13.3.4 マイクロポストを削除する」で躓いています

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[Rails Tutorial13章 13.3.4 マイクロポストを削除する](https://railstutorial.jp/chapters/user_microposts?version=5.1#sec-destroying_microposts)　の個所で削除がうまくいきません。
起きている現象としては、マイクロポストの削除リンクをクリックするとHomeページに飛び、deleteをクリックしたマイクロポストは残ったままになっています。

デバッグにて、micropost_controller.rbの`correct_user`メソッド内の`@micropost`がnilになっていることまでは調べました。が、デバッグで代入式の`current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])`を確認するときちんと返ってきます。似た現象を見たことがある方がいらしたら助言をいただけると助かります。

Comment: `@micropost.destroy`を`@micropost.destroy!` にすると、何か変化はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

お騒がせしました。自己解決できました。
@micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])　の左辺のスペースが全角になっていたことが悪さをしていたようです。
初歩的なミスで申し訳ありません。